# Scala mockito: Delay Mockito.when().thenReturn(someFuture)

Tags: scala, mockito, delay, future

```
val future = new CompletableFuture()
future.complete(someObject)

Mockito.when(_).thenReturn{
    future
}
```

for the above code, I want to test the situation if there is a delay in val future: CompletableFuture to complete.

how can I force the future to delay in thenReturn?

I tried something like:

```
Mockito.when(_).thenReturn{
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    future
}
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `Thread.sleep(2000)` inside the future.

You probably would like to achieve something like this:

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.when

object MainClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mock = Mockito.mock(classOf[SomeTrait])

    when(mock.doSmth).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync[String](() => {
      println(s"[${Instant.now()}] run future")
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        "Something"
      } finally {
        println(s"[${Instant.now()}] end future")
      }
    }))

    val future = mock.doSmth

    println(s"[${Instant.now()}] end main")
    future.get()
    println(s"[${Instant.now()}] result: ${future.get()}")
  }
}

trait SomeTrait {
  def doSmth: CompletableFuture[String]
}
```

output:

```
[2019-05-13T20:55:34.079Z] end main
[2019-05-13T20:55:34.079Z] run future
[2019-05-13T20:55:36.096Z] end future
[2019-05-13T20:55:36.097Z] result: Something
```

P.S. execution of the CompletableFuture starts when you declare it to return. If you need to start the execution of the future at some time after this declaration - you have to use `scala.concurrent.Promise` and wrap your CompletableFuture by `scala.concurrent.Future`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, i am actually using java Completable future in my scala code, with Completable future, is it possible to delay it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn` to simulate the wait time.

Refer this - https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html

Following is the java equivalent code -

```
Mockito.when(<your method call>).thenAnswer(new Answer<CompletableFuture>() {
   @Override
   public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      return future;
   }
})
```

Comment: this invocation suspends the current thread. It is equivalent to put ```Thread.sleep(2000); ``` before ```Mockito.when(<your method call>)...```

Answer (score 0):

With mockito-scala you can write something like

```
when(_) thenAnswer {
   Thread.sleep(2000)
   future
}
```

which is arguably cleaner and easier to understand